# python-writing q as a function of i in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm completely new to python so forgive me if this question is stupid.I am try to code for a Fibonacci sequence and wanted to know if there is a way for me to write q as a function of i in a for loop.
like:

```
 for i in range (1,x): 
    q(i)=q(i-1)+q(i-2)
```

Comment: Yes, q is just a list instead of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### With lists

Yes, you can do that:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> q = 10*[1]
>>> for i in range(2,x):
...     q[i] = q[i-1] + q[i-2]
... 
>>> q
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Notes:

1. Subscripts in python are denoted with square brackets not parens.
2. Because the calculation needs `q[i-2]`, the calculation needs to start at index `i=2`.

#### With functions

```
>>> def qfn(i):
...     return 1 if i <=1 else qfn(i-1) + qfn(i-2)
... 
>>> qfn(8)
34
>>> qfn(9)
55
```